# Is there any way to enable "re-run previous" in vscode?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am trying to accomplish this using the vscode-r extensions. However this maybe has a more general answer. In the RStudio IDE, there is the ability to "re-run previous" such that the block of code you most recently ran will be run again including some small changes in that code?

So the workflow would be:

```
my_fun(arg1 = "foo")
```

make some changes to the code:

```
my_fun(arg1 = "bar")
```

Then run a shortcut to simply rerun the line (or lines) of code recently run.

Any idea how to set this up in vscode?

Comment: if it is not already done why don't you make it in an extension

Comment: I'd love to and would love to spend the time but am at a bit of loss of where to even start.